# Drupal group field

Tags: drupal-7

Every album has an artist attached to it using node reference, I need to get all the albums attached to this artist how can I do that using the same view, because what i got from the same view duplication from the same artist ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Having a bit more info in the question would help - specifically:

1. What version of Views and Drupal?  (I'm assuming latest - Views 3 and Drupal 7)
2. What exactly results would you like to see and what are you filtering on?  (Screenshot of your View would hopefully do the trick)

I think I might be able to answer anyway - here are three key things that could help:

**Relationship Basics**

In Views setup a *Relationship* and then use that relationship when you create fields.  In the image below I have a slideshow node that has node references to slides.  So I've setup a relationship from the Slideshow to the Slide.  Then that relationship in turn is used to pull the fields from the Slide instead of the Slideshow under *Fields*.

[image: Basic Views relationship screenshot]

**Views Distinct**

If you're only issue is that you're getting duplicate results, sometimes an easy solution is turning on *Distinct* for the query.  In the View, under Advanced click on *Query settings* and check *Distinct*.

[image: Turn on Distinct in Views]

**Reverse Relationships**

It sounds like you might actually need to setup a reverse relationship in this case if you're loading the artist node and then trying to get the node references back to all of that artist's albums.  You can see each node reference has a corresponding entry when you're adding a relationship to pick the *reverse* of that node reference.

[image: Reverse node reference relationship field in Views]

Comment: 1-What version of Views and Drupal? (I'm assuming latest - Views 3 and Drupal 7)

Yes it's the latest

2-What exactly results would you like to see and what are you 
filtering on?

I want to see artist details like the albums (Node) he attached to and videos attached to the same artist in one view how can i get all the links like an array from albums or any other type ?

i need to post to you an image for the view i have put i don't know to post it to you from here :( here it's

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgxskl6f6rlbzh3/drupal.jpg